# Core data adds attribute to an entity automatically

Tags: ios, core-data, relationships

I have two core data entities say 'Task' and 'State'. 'Task' has 2 attributes - 'currentState'(which of type 'State') and 'nextPossibleStates'(which is of type NSSet<'State'>).
The issue here is when i parse the payload and save the 'currentState' to 'Task' in DB, it automatically adds that current state entry into the 'nextPossibleStates'. For example if there are 5 next possible states, after i parse and save the currentState and nextPossibleStates to db, the count of nextPossibleStates is 6, which actually included the currentState too!

I presume this is causing due to some core data model relationships. But i do not find something fishy in the tons of relationships that are made already.. So is there any kind of core data relationship that could cause the above thing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how much easier would this be, if you shared some code?

Comment: There is nothing in Core Data that would automatically link these two relationships. You need to post details about your code and your model, because right now no good answer is possible.

Comment: How can we see anything fishy if you haven't provided any code?